# Delete rows in sybase with joins

Tags: sql, join, sybase, sql-delete

I'm trying to run a query to delete all rows with specific ID's that do not have the most recent timestamp.  I am receiving an error telling me that the table "c" does not exist...

Here is the query...

```
DELETE c
FROM 
    "sac"."vendor_item_cost" c
JOIN(
    SELECT
        c1.Vendor_id,
        c1.Item_Number,
        MAX(c1.Last_edit_timestamp) as [Date]
    FROM
        "sac"."vendor_item_cost" c1
    JOIN
        "sac"."vendor_item_cost" c2
    ON
        c1.Vendor_id = c2.Vendor_id AND c1.Item_Number = c2.Item_Number
    GROUP BY
        c1.Vendor_id, c1.Item_Number
) q
ON
    c.Vendor_id = q.vendor_id AND c.Item_Number = q.Item_Number AND c.Last_edit_timestamp <> q.[Date]
```

Running a SELECT statement with the same code returns the correct rows that I am trying to delete without any problem.  See below...

```
SELECT 
    c.Store_number, 
    c.Vendor_id, 
    c.Cost, 
    c.Item_Number, 
    c.Last_edit_timestamp 
FROM 
    "sac"."vendor_item_cost" as c
JOIN(
    SELECT
        c1.Vendor_id,
        c1.Item_Number,
        MAX(c1.Last_edit_timestamp) as [Date]
    FROM
        "sac"."vendor_item_cost" c1
    JOIN
        "sac"."vendor_item_cost" c2
    ON
        c1.Vendor_id = c2.Vendor_id AND c1.Item_Number = c2.Item_Number
    GROUP BY
        c1.Vendor_id, c1.Item_Number
) q
ON
    c.Vendor_id = q.vendor_id AND c.Item_Number = q.Item_Number AND c.Last_edit_timestamp <> q.[Date]
```

I've never worked with sybase before, am I just using the wrong syntax for a delete statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
DELETE "sac"."vendor_item_cost"
FROM "sac"."vendor_item_cost" as c,(SELECT c1.Vendor_id, c1.Item_Number, MAX(c1.Last_edit_timestamp) as [Date]
    FROM
        "sac"."vendor_item_cost" c1
    JOIN
        "sac"."vendor_item_cost" c2
    ON
        c1.Vendor_id = c2.Vendor_id AND c1.Item_Number = c2.Item_Number
    GROUP BY
        c1.Vendor_id, c1.Item_Number
) q
WHERE
    c.Vendor_id = q.vendor_id 
AND c.Item_Number = q.Item_Number 
AND c.Last_edit_timestamp <> q.[Date]
```